# mouse over zoom not working in magento

Tags: magento

I want to install a jquery zoom box on my magento website, I have tried almost every thing found on the internet. am I doing something wrong? But I cannot seen to get jquery mouse over zoom to work on my magento site, I have put in jquery noconflict in my jquery files as well. I am using magento 1.5.1 , I have even tried installing magento extensions of magic zoom, cloud zoom , jqzoom but nothing is working.

Any help will be appreciated

thx in advance

Comment: try starting the jquery command by $j instead of just $

Comment: have you get any solution..please share.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you may please check whether there is any js error.
2. Sometimes the extension you installed may be in the default directory of the template.So please check view source of the product detail page, whether there exits the content. Otherwise please copy that template and layout from the default folder to your theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser is Chrome, CTRL+SHIFT+J will open the javascript console.

In my case, it told me that the magento /js/scriptaculous folder was missing, which seems to be a bug in Magento Connect for 1.8.1.0. Copying that folder from an archived earlier version on the Magento website fixed this.

The original question was about a different version of Magento so may not have the same cause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this: http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/magento-community-tutorials/53-theming-magento-23-better-product-zoom.

I've used it and it works like a charm!