# Magento mouseover zoom / cloud zoom issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

Trying to improve magento's default product image gallery/zoom feature.

Firstly, the first trouble I had was a 404 error in the admin panel, and this was the fix:

system / permission / roles , click on your username "administrators" , click on "role users" on the left side, then click "reset filter" and finally "save role"

taken from this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEgtVv_a1AE

I thought I would post that because from reading around there seemed to be a lot of people looking for this solution, so I hope that helps someone.

But I am still having trouble getting the "cloud zoom" extensions to work, I have tried 3 of them, VS product image zoom, Cueblocks zoom, and Moo Cloudzoom. and none of them are working.

I found this advice here : [mouse over zoom not working in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801640/mouse-over-zoom-not-working-in-magento)

and yes indeed I have errors in the JS console on chrome, but alas, I do not understand the errors or how to troubleshoot them.

If someone could give a fix, a hint, or advice I would appreciate it a lot, as always.

I just think the standard magento product zoom that opens in a new window is not very user friendly.

This is the site I am trying to get it working on http://watchgearonline.co.uk/watch-straps/nato-strap-black-and-blue.html

currently Moo Cloudzoom is installed ....

Edit: This is the error log in the Js console on chrome, there are 5 errors it seems:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'zoom' script.js:9
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://watchgearonline.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/css/print.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://watchgearonline.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/slider_btn_zoom_out.gif
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://watchgearonline.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/images/slider_btn_zoom_in.gif
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
    at CSRecorder.onQueryStateCompleted (chrome-extension://cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/content_scripts/recorder.js:43:13)
    at messageListener (extensions::messaging:343:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:394:22)
    at Event.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:378:27)
    at Event.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:400:17)
    at dispatchOnMessage (extensions::messaging:307:22) nato-strap-black-and-blue.html:1
```

Comment: add jQuery.noConflict()..it may be conflicting with your prototype.

Comment: paste your error here

Comment: hi, I posted into the original comment above^ thanks for looking

Comment: Hello, do you still need an answer? I looked at your website. Is it still supposed to be using Moo Cloudzoom? If it is, then the module is not installed properly because the javascript file cloudzoom.js is not being loaded. I will help you but please give me an updated on your current site zoom method.

Comment: hi, yes i do still need an answer. i installed Moo Cloudzoom via the magento connect panel, and it shows Moo Cloudzoom in the backend too. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some of the required module files. You can download the module from [here](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/magento) (click the middle blue button 'magento package') then unzip and upload it to your Magento server - or use it to check that all the files are there and in particular:

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\starplugins-cloudzoom.xml
```

and

```
\js\starplugins\cloudzoom.js
```

You can check that the module is active by looking in the Magento admin at system->configuration->developer->advanced.

Ensure that after upload (or install) that you log out of the admin area, log back in, refresh all the caches including Cache Storage and the Magento cache and if you use the compiler (system->tools->compiler) then disable and then recompile.

The basic problem is that your page is missing (at least) the lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://watchgearonline.co.uk/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://watchgearonline.co.uk/js/starplugins/cloudzoom.js"></script>
```

which suggests the module is not installed correctly or somethign is interfering with the XML that adds the JavaScript and the CSS to the `<head>` section.